# Use NIC and WiFi at the same time with VMware on a laptop

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation, laptop

Normally on a laptop if you plug in a LAN cable the WiFi Internet connection will be disabled.  The specific laptop in question is a Dell XPS 15 Core i7.

I would like to:

1. Plug a LAN cable in and have a VMware Guest OS take control of that connection.  This is where it will get its Internet connection from.
2. Have the Host OS use WiFi for its Internet connection

Is the above possible or will the laptop always override this by shutting off the WiFi?

The product could be VMware Workstation or VirtualBox, it doesn't matter.

Comment: VMware is a company. Which product of theirs are you using? Using "VMware" alone is like saying "I'm having a problem with Microsoft". Please update the tags of this question with the appropriate VMware product.

Comment: VMWare workstation or VirtualBox, I have access to both.  Normally if I plug a lan cable into a laptop the wifi  shuts off, since a laptop will only use one internet connection.

Comment: "I plug a lan cable into a laptop the wifi shuts off" - not necessarily true, in most cases the routing metrics will dynamically update to favoring the wired route.

Answer (score 0):

In order to steer a VM towards one NIC versus another, you need to set it up for "Bridge" mode networking versus "NAT" where NAT will follow the host's network routing table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your Dell, but a few people I work with had the same issue with their company issued HP laptops.  A quick trip into the BIOS to turn off the "Disable WiFi when wired interface is active" feature fixed them right up.